# How to schedule an oozie coordinator on the first 12 week days of the month?

Tags: bigdata, oozie, hortonworks-data-platform, oozie-coordinator

Is there any way i can ask an oozie coordinator to run a workflow only on the first 12 week days (i.e. exclude week ends) of each month ?

Thanks !

Edit : For example in december 2017 i would like the scheduler to behave like this

```
December 1st, friday -> run the workflow
December 2nd and 3rd, week ends -> do not run the workflow
December 4th to 8th, monday to friday -> run the worflow
December 9th and 10th, week end -> do not run the workflow
December 11th to 15th, monday to friday -> run the workflow
December 16th and 17th, week end -> do not run the workflow
December 18th, monday -> run the workflow
```

In total the workflow will run 12 times in a month excluding all the weekends.

Hope it is a bit more clear.

Comment: what you mean by first 12 week days? not clear. More detailed explanation is here for scheduling http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/04/how-to-use-cron-like-scheduling-in-apache-oozie/

Comment: Thanks Amit, I tried to clarify a bit. And thanks for the link, i'm new to Oozie so i'm sure this link will help.

Comment: Too complex for CRON syntax. Run the workflow everyday (or all 16 first days) ; start with some action that can compute the status of the current day then spit out the result to Oozie via `<capture-output/>` (e.g. shell or java) ; use that output in a "decision" to continue the workflow or just stop. But that means you have some work to do.

Comment: Thanks Samson, i'll try something like what you suggested. When the solution is found i'll post it here